# Kubernetes: preferredDuringScheduling

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

### Background

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform. I have 2 Node-Pools in my cluster: `A` and `B`. `B` is cheaper (depends on hardware). I prefer that my deployment will run on `B`. Unless no free resources in `B`. In that case, new pods will deploy to `A`.

So I added this section to deployment YAML:

```
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: B
            operator: Exists
        weight: 100
```

So I giving more weight to node-pool B.

At start, it's working good. I came back after 24 hours and found that some pods are deployed to node-pool A while I have free resources (un-allocated machines) in node B. This is wast of money.

### So, how its happen?

I sure that the property `nodeAffinity` is working currectly. I suspect that at same point, node pool B was running without any FREE resources. At this point, the cluster want to grow... The new pod was deployed to node pool A. Until here, everything is fine...

### What I want to achieve?

Lets say that after an hour, from lack of node-pool `B` resources time, There are plany of resources free to alocation. I want that Kubernetes will move the existing pods from A to their new house in node pool B.

I looking for something like `preferredDuringSchedulingPreferedDuringExecution`.

### Question

Is this possible?

### Update

Based on @Hitobat answer, I tried to use this code:

```
 spec:
   tolerations:
    - key: A
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoExecute"
      tolerationSeconds: 60
```

Unfortunately, After waiting enough time, I still see pods on my `A` nodepool. I did something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can taint pool A. Then configure *all* your pods to tolerate the taint, but with a tolerationSeconds for the duration you want. This is in addition to the config you already did for pool B.

The effect will be that the pod is scheduled to A if it won't fit on B, but then after a while will be evicted (and hopefully rescheduled onto B again).

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions

Comment: Hey, it's not clear to me. I tried to use this mechanism without success. See my code on "Update" section (main message). What I should change?

Comment: There's also now this tool which may help. https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/descheduler

Answer (score 0):

Pod Affinity and nodeAffinity resource request are what scheduling uses to determine where to schedule a new pod. So, as long as the Pod is running, it will not be moved. So, the answer to this question is No. I will recommend filing a [feature request](https://github.com/marbl/canu/projects) on Github. For more information on this topic, see the nodeAffinity section of this the following [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature)